What is the most efficient way to create mutable slice of mutable slices in Rust?
I use an external library function, that get as input the type:
&mut [&mut [f32]], which should represent a 2-d array with fixed dimensions.
For better performance, I would like to create a 1-dimension array, so all the data will sit continuously in memory, and transform it to the above form.
However, I am little struggling due to lack of experience in Rust, and I wonder what is the "Rust way" to achieve my goal.
One way I could think of, is creating a new Vec, iterating the 1-dimensional arra, and push every slice to it, but it feels like a waste of memory.
Thanks in advance.

You cannot convert a vec<f32> to &mut [&mut [f32]] because the data does not have the right shape. You could use Vec<&mut [f32]> for example, this would probably be efficient only if the outer dimension is small. You could use a library like this one which defines such views for you.

Why is a 1-dimensional array would be more performant in your use-case? How exactly are you organizing the array differently in memory?

FYI, functions usually should not take &mut [&mut [T]], they should take &mut [impl AsMut<[T]>]. If this is your only option, then your idea of making a new Vec is good, and if by "fixed" you mean fixed at compile time, then you could put them in an array.

Once you have your data in a single contiguous vector, you can use chunks_exact_mut to obtain an iterator over each mutable subslice, but you'd have to collect that into another Vec in order to pass the resulting slice to the library.

@Codebling maybe I am wrong, but if I create 2d-array, is it still guaranteed to lay in the same chunk in memory?

@eggyal can you please post an answer with your solution with example?

barak1412 yes! A 1D of integers holds all of the integers contiguously. A "2D array" is really just a 1D array of 1D arrays. When you ask if it will always be in the same chunk of memory, the answer is yes. If you're asking which elements will be contiguous, the elements of every "row" would be contiguous, and every row would be contiguous as well. If you need a specific layout that you need, you may be able to optimize further.

In my humble opinion, there is a bar for performance for every project, and as long as one expects their code to stay above that level of performance, then one should focus on clean and maintainable code before focusing on optimizations.

@Codebling I agree with you. Good to know about the 2d array, thanks!

Once you have your data in a single contiguous slice (such as in a Vec), you can use chunks_exact_mut to obtain an iterator over each mutable subslice, but you'd have to collect that into a(nother) Vec in order to pass the resulting slice to the library.  For example:
/// Given the row-first two-dimensional array represented by
/// `contiguous_rows_of_cols`, return (in order) each row as a subslice.
fn to_vec_of_slices<T>(contiguous_rows_of_cols: &mut [T], cols: usize) -> Vec<&mut [T]> {
    contiguous_rows_of_cols.chunks_exact_mut(cols).collect()
}

See it on the playground.

You can't turn a Vec<f32> into a &mut [&mut [f32]], but you can cheaply construct a &mut [&mut [f32]] from a Vec<f32> by first turning it into a &mut [f32] and then simply wrapping that in another &mut [].
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1.0, 2.0, 3.0];
    let inner = &mut *v;
    add(&mut [inner], 10.0);
    println!("{v:?}");
    // [11.0, 12.0, 13.0]
}

fn add(arr: &mut [&mut [f32]], addend: f32) {
    for inner in arr {
        for x in inner.iter_mut() {
            *x += addend;
        }
    } 
}


How does the slice generated that way "represent a 2-d array with fixed dimensions." that are different from (1, N)?
